# Device not starting EMM agent

Tags: android, wso2-iot

Good day

I have recently run into an issue with WSO2 EMM v 2.0.1 and need some assistance.

The Android EMM agent is successfully installed, enrolled and selected as a the device manager on a few devices, the WSO2 agent functions 100% for some time but we have seen some scenarios where devices do not start the WSO2 agent on bootup.

When I manually start the application again the device starts the agent on reboot.

From my side it looks like the OS is not starting this application after the device has been dormant for x amount of time.

Has anyone else experienced this issue?

Comment: It has a BroadcastReceiver to start after the boot up. Please check on this https://github.com/wso2/product-emm/blob/release-2.0.1/modules/mobile-agents/android/client/client/src/main/java/org/wso2/emm/agent/services/DeviceStartupIntentReceiver.java. If you are testing the EMM I recommend to move to latest IoT Server 3.0.0

Comment: This happens when your refresh token expired. Please increase the refresh token validity from the /repository/conf/indentity.xml and restart the server then enroll the device back.